# Bootstrap 4.4.1 place button or font awesome near input

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I need to place the button near the input. I have tried to use input-group, and checkbox-inline and to use smaller or larger columns.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="MainDiagnosis">Main Diagnosis Code</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" disabled="disabled" id="MainDiagnosis" name="MainDiagnosis" type="text" value="">
                        <input type="button" value="click">
                        </div>
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="MainDiagnosis" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
               
                </div>

<div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="PatientAvailableFrom">Available From</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control text-box single-line hasDatepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Available From must be a date." data-val-required="Availability from is required" id="PatientAvailableFrom" name="PatientAvailableFrom" type="datetime" value="">
                    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="PatientAvailableFrom" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Adding d-flex to the div resulted in:
[image]

Comment: something like this? [https://codepen.io/fede811/pen/BaNdLYQ](https://codepen.io/fede811/pen/BaNdLYQ)

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy this the code i have, i need to modify it

Comment: only html css etc without asp please

Comment: If my answer actually answers your question kindly mark it as answered for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `d-flex` class to your div :

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="MainDiagnosis">Main Diagnosis Code</label>
  <div class="col-md-8 d-flex">
    <input class="form-control text-box single-line" disabled="disabled" id="MainDiagnosis" name="MainDiagnosis" type="text" value="">
    <input type="button" value="click">
  </div>
  <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="MainDiagnosis" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="PatientAvailableFrom">Available From</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input class="form-control text-box single-line hasDatepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Available From must be a date." data-val-required="Availability from is required" id="PatientAvailableFrom" name="PatientAvailableFrom" type="datetime"
      value="">
    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="PatientAvailableFrom" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```